# Using $index with the AngularJS 'ng-options' directive?

Tags: angularjs, html-select

Say that I bind an array to a `select` tag using the following:

```
<select ng-model="selData" ng-options="$index as d.name for d in data">
```

In this case, the associated `option` tags are assigned a sequence of index values: (0, 1, 2, ...). However, when I select something from the drop-down, the value of `selData` is getting bound to `undefined`. Should the binding actually work?

On the other hand, say that I instead do the following:

```
<select ng-model="selData" ng-options="d as d.name for d in data">
```

Here, the `option` tags get the same index, but the entire object is bound on change. Is it working this way by design, or this behavior simply a nice bug or side-effect of AngularJS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$index is defined for ng-repeat, not select.  I think this explains the `undefined`.  (So, no, this shouldn't work.)

Angular supports binding on the entire object.  The documentation could be worded better to indicate this, but it does hint at it: "ngOptions ... should be used instead of ngRepeat when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value."

Comment: See Harry's answer below, which provides a simple workaround.

Answer (score 204):

Since arrays are very similar to objects in JavaScript, you can use the syntax for "object data sources".  The trick is in the **brackets** in the `ng-options` part:

```
var choices = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three'
];
```

In the template:

```
<select
  ng-model="model.choice"
  ng-options="idx as choice for (idx, choice) in choices">
</select>
```

In the end, `model.choice` will have the value 0, 1, or 2.  When it's 0, you will see `One`; 1 will display `Two`, etc.  But in the model, you will see the index value only.

I adapted this information from "Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS" by PACKT Publishing, and verified at the [Angular reference documentation for select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: Clever trick. Exactly what I needed, except the model is set as string instead of number.

Comment: Thank you so much .. amazing hw such small things escape your mind when its the right time to implement it

Comment: Can you clarify your use of the word 'brackets'? Do you mean the pair of variables inside the parentheses for ng-options?

Comment: Yes, @broc.seib -- the "(idx, choice)" part.

Comment: This approach messes up the order of the select elements

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @NewDev.  Can you show an example of how it messes up the order of select elements?

Comment: I should have clarified that it applies when you have more than 10 choices. Then the order of items becomes: `0, 1, 10, 11, ... 2,`

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work when setting a preselected option. Although the ngModel clearly gets a number when selected manually in UI, you can't preseleect assigning an index to ngModel. Seems like a bug in AngularJS or not intended use. After all it is a trick for a non-array

Comment: If you need ```idx``` to be a number, just times it by 1 and that parses it as an int. ```idx*1 as choice for (idx, choice) in choices```

Comment: @KirillSlatin, it works for me after adapting the hack from @MichaelWilson. By default angular will make `idx` a string rather than a number.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) the given solution is not valid for array data sources. At least not for recent Angular versions.

Comment: @Jim Cote, you should change this answer as actually your question's answer. It totally works!

Answer (score 45):

Since you can't use `$index` but you can try `indexOf`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
          ng-model="selectedItem"
          ng-options="values.indexOf(selectedItem) as selectedItem for selectedItem in values"></select>
    selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values = ["Value1","Value2"];
    $scope.selectedItem = 0;
}
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/30/)</kbd>

*Comment:*

`Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported in IE7 (8)

Comment: Maybe the only thing to point out is that `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported in IE8 (and IE7).

Comment: Another thing is performance .. for every item you have to go through array and find its index while printing out..

Comment: This is especially useful for incorrectly defined arrays, where index may contain keys other than numbers. Also, Array.prototype.indexOf can be polyfilled, so that's not a big issue.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the array values are not unique

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ng-value='$index' in `<option>` tag.

```
<select ng-model="selData">
 <option ng-repeat="d in data track by $index" ng-value="$index">
   {{d.name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: `ng-value` will NOT hold numbers, only strings

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$index` inside select tags. Use `$index` inside the option tags if you want to use the array indexes as either values or options.

```
<option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.username}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
```

If you want to use inside values just put it in the value attribute as binding expression like

```
<option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{$index+1}}">{{user.username}}</option>
```

and my controller code be like:

```
var users = ['username':'bairavan', 'username':'testuser'];
```