# Editing property from Object in ng-repeat from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I'm listing an array of objects saved into Localstorage in a table-like layout.

Each row displays data saved in a particular object. I want to be able to edit and update certain properties from the object once it has already been saved into LocalStorage.

This is how a couple of my objects looks like:

```
[{
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"20.22",
  "car":"396",
  "driver":"Seb",
  "from":"A",
  "destination":"B",
  "pax":"3",
  "arrival":"23.10"
},
{
  "date":"2014 10 16",
  "time":"23.22",
  "car":"46",
  "driver":"Eric",
  "from":"C",
  "destination":"E",
  "pax":"3",
  "arrival":"00.10"
}]
```

So far my frontend code displaying the **Destination** property looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3" 
     ng-show="editItem == false" 
     ng-hide="editItem">{{record.destination}}</div> 
// Shows current value

<div class="col-md-3" 
     ng-show="editItem == true" 
     ng-hide="!editItem">
   <select class="form-control" 
           ng-model="locationList2" 
           ng-options="location.place for location in locationlist | orderBy:'place'">
     <option value="">Destination</option>
   </select> 
</div>
// Shows select with options to be picked to update property

<div class="col-md-1">
         <button ng-click="editItem = !editItem" 
                 ng-show="!editItem">Edit</button>
         <button ng-click="editData(record); editItem = !editItem" 
                 ng-show="editItem">Ok</button>
</div>
//Toggles between current value and select and triggers editData function
```

**Relevant JS:**

```
$scope.editData = function (record) {
    record.destination = $scope.locationList2;
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
}
```

So far when I trigger **editData** it just deletes the Destination property, it doesn't update it with the model of locationList2 from the Select.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here's the complete ng-repeat piece of code:

```
    <div class="row msf-row" ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.car}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">{{record.from}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" 
         ng-show="editItem == false" 
         ng-hide="editItem">
           {{record.destination}}              
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" 
         ng-show="editItem == true" 
         ng-hide="!editItem">
            <select class="form-control" 
               ng-model="locationList2" 
               ng-options="location.place for location in locationlist | orderBy:'place'">
                  <option value="">Destination</option>
            </select> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.pax}}</div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
         <button 
           ng-click="editItem = !editItem" 
           ng-show="!editItem">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
         </button>

         <button 
           ng-click="editData(record); editItem = !editItem" 
           ng-show="editItem">
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
         </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Also, I here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vEjzjG0Lt1gzbNvGfSqo?p=preview) to ilustrate the issue!

Add a driver, car code and location before starting to see the app running and the mentioned problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So what you'll want to do is to update the localStorage entry after an edit, correct?

Comment: I have a saved {{record.destination}} property, I can click on the edit button and a Select appears replacing {{record.destination}} in the view, I want to be able to select an alternative in the Select and when triggering ng-click="editData(recordlist); save it replacing/updating the current {{record.destination}}.

Comment: Yes @bebraw, that is correct. But only certain properties from a particular item from an ng-repeat list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) as an abstraction over LocalStorage API.

If you want to just hack it, you can do something along `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))` when setting data and use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))` to extract it. LocalStorage doesn't deal with objects by default so we have to serialize it.

Regardless of the solution you choose, it could be a good idea to extend your edit a bit:

```
$scope.editData = function (recordlist) {
    $scope.recordlist.destination = $scope.locationList2;

    // replace whole LocalStorage data here now. no need to "patch" it
    updateLocalStorage('data', <data containing your objects goes here>);
}
```

If you have multiple ways to modify the data and want to avoid explicit update, you could set up a watcher instead:

```
$scope.$watch(<data name goes here>, function(newVal) {
    // update your LocalStorage now
});
```

### Why it fails with `ng-repeat`?

The reason you see the behavior is quite simple. `$scope.locationList2` is a single variable that gets bound for each member created by `ng-repeat`. That explains why it stays empty during edit.

You will need to bind the data using some other way. Consider binding it directly to your `record` models. Example: [AngularJS - Using $index in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options) .

### Solution

The original code had bits like this:

JS:

```
$scope.editData = function (record) {
    record.destination = $scope.location;
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="location" ng-options="location.place for location in locationlist | orderBy:'place'">
    <option value="">Destination</option>
</select>
```

Note that the markup is inside a `ng-repeat` and effectively each item created by it points at the same location! This isn't good.

To make it work I changed it like this:

JS:

```
$scope.editData = function () {
  jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="record.destination" ng-options="location.place as location.place for location in locationlist | orderBy:'place'">
    <option value="">Destination</option>
</select>
```

As mentioned above the JS could be replaced by a watcher. The important thing to note here is that I bind the data directly to the records. That avoid hassle at `editData` and more importantly gets rid of the problematic `ng-model` reference.

Comment: I updated my question just a sec ago. So far, if I trigger the editData function and I do record.destination = 'test';, it will work perfectly and update the property to destination : test;, but when I try do capture the data from the Select using the locationList2 model, it won't.

Comment: What is the relation between `record` and `recordList`? Do you have a `ng-repeat` there? Can you verify that when you modify the record, the recordList gets modified as well? I'm guessing that's where the problem might be.

Comment: I included the whole ng-repeat for clarification. Thanks for the help and the patience!

Comment: @EricMitjans Hey, did you try modifying records directly? Alternatively you can set up a proxy (`angular.copy`) during edit and then `angular.extend` on save. I can set up an example of that.

Comment: Hi @bebraw! If you check the Relevant JS part, you can see that I already tried to modify record directly, and actually when I pass  record.destination = 'test'; it updates the value correctly. The problem is with the Select value and ng-model. Im at work right now and I cant take care of it, as soon as Im home Ill take a look at possible solutions to pass the value from the Select model to the controller and record it in record.destination.

Comment: @EricMitjans Ok, no probs. Please set up a http://plnkr.co/ so it's easier to debug what's going on.

Comment: Its gonna be a pain because the whole localstorage stuff, but I can definitely try. Thanks @bebraw!!

Comment: There we go! http://plnkr.co/edit/vEjzjG0Lt1gzbNvGfSqo?p=preview
Please add driver, car and location before, its gonna be easier...

Comment: @EricMitjans Here's a fixed version, http://plnkr.co/edit/gw0kfwDKuBdvrvwvFS5E?p=preview . The problem was that multiple items of that `ng-repeat` pointed at the same model. It is better to point at records directly. I'll expand on this in my answer in a bit.