# Pre-select option form ng-options list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I'm trying to preselect a item in the list which is generated by ng-options directive. Could someone please tell me whats happening in the plunker?

http://plnkr.co/edit/GTnR76HEnB5NxQRe484m?p=preview

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function MyCntrl($scope) {
      $scope.prop = {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Service",
        "values": [{
          'name': "Service 1"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 2"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 3"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 4"
        }]
      };
      $scope.selected1 = $scope.prop.values[1]
      $scope.selected2 = {
        "name": "Service 2"
      }

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    Works <br>
  <select ng-model="selected1" ng-options="v.name for v in prop.values">
    </select> {{selected1}} <br>
    Does not work. Why? <br>
    <select ng-model="selected2" ng-options="v.name  for v in prop.values">
    </select>
    {{selected2}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bijay Rai's statement is correct but not full answer.

`ngOption` has rather complicated expressions and you should bother to examine [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). If you change the way the option's object is being tracked you can avoid using `same object` by reference as stated. For example, use `select as` pattern

```
<select ng-model="selected2" ng-options="v.id as v.name for v in prop.values">
</select>
```

Then you can simply assign selected like this:

```
  $scope.selected2 = 3;
```

Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICEdO6MpFLZbmYEQ29Y0)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I need the selected object. I mean I need ``{'id': 3, 'name': 'Service 3'}`` not just 3. How do i do that ?. Btw I did read documentation, but its not a easy syntax to understand, more example will help.

Comment: the question was 'WHAT is happening' and this is the answer. What to do with it is up to you :) Actually when you have an index of selected item you can always get it from your array

Comment: Examine SO about this, for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.prop = {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Service",
        "values": [{
          'name': "Service 1"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 2"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 3"
        }, {
          'name': "Service 4"
        }]
      };
```

*ng-options* getting data from *prop.values*....
so *selected1* is working cause it is predefined as *$scope.prop.values[1]*

whereas *selected2* is not referring to data inside *prop.values*.....