# Get index of selected item in a select listbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-click="getIndex($index)" size="14" ng-model="playlist.fileSelected" ng-options="saveFile for saveFile in playlist.playlist"></select>
```

$index comes out as undefined. How can i get the index of the select listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

Credit goes to the answers for this question.
[AngularJS - Using $index in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options)

There's also an explanation on why `$index` doesn't work with ng-options.

```
<select ng-click="getIndex(saveFile)" size="14" ng-model="saveFile" ng-options="index as saveFile for (index, saveFile) in playlist.playlist"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs, you get the index of an array through:

```
yourArray.indexOf(yourItem)
```

So, in your case, something like:

```
playlist.playlist.indexOf(playlist.fileSelected)
```