# ng-model isn't updating when I change a select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box with some `ng-options`, but it's not updating the `ng-model` when I select an option. I have a fiddle up at http://jsfiddle.net/32tntojs/ to view the source.

My HTML is

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
PARENTID: {{ parent_id }}
<select  ng-model="parent_id" ng-options="project.id as project.groupingName for project in projects track by $index"></select>
</div>
```

and when I select something, the `parent_id` doesn't update. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <select  ng-model="parent_id" ng-options="project.id as project.groupingName for project in projects track by project.id"></select>

track by project.id

Comment: @dharmesh Can't he use the `$index` of his controller?

Comment: @DavidR The value as text syntax is entirely proper.

Comment: @Lex I see.. Deleted my comment.

Comment: The one part that I think is invalid in the ng-option is the `track by $index` - that [`$index` is not defined for `ng-options`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options).  You could however use something like: `ng-options="$index as project.groupingName for ($index, project) in projects track by $index"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/32tntojs/3/

Your `projects` array of objects does not contain `id` so replaced it with `gid`

HTML :

```
<select ng-model="parent_id" ng-options="project.gid as project.groupingName for project in projects"></select>
```

Another mistake: `as` shouldn't be used with `track by`

Refer AngularJs Docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

`Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your project objects do not have an id property.  When I inspect the select element, all the option values are `undefined`.

The `ng-option` syntax looks fine and the ng-model does in fact update when I change it to:

```
<select  ng-model="parent_id" ng-options="project.gid as project.groupingName for project in projects track by $index"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$index` in ng-options (as @plong0 points out).
This does work:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  PARENTID: {{ parent_id }}
  <select  ng-model="parent_id" ng-options="project.id as project.groupingName for project in projects track by $index"></select>
</div>
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn4feofd/).