# function not execute in controller and factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller, factory

i'm developing an app that should call a controller where there are some functions, because i receive from a server (localhost in this moment) a JSON array with a structure like this:

```
[{
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "09:45"
  }, {
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "16:50"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "11:25"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "12:30"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "16:10"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "17:25"
  }]
```

And then i print it in two selects in a form in this way:

**SELECT 1**:
17/11/2016, 18/11/2016, 21/11/2016

**SELECT 2**:
09:45, 16:50 **OR** 11:25, 12:30 **OR** 16:10, 17:25 based on the choice in the first select

Up to this point there are no problems but now it should execute a function that post the coice of the user to the server but the app doesn't execute it.

This is my code,

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);

DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService'];

function DefaultController(dataService) {
  var vm = this;

  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.data = data;
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          schedules: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }

          result.schedules.push({
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
          });
        }

        return result;
      }
    };

    return $http.get('http://<path>/api/apiTimes.php', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);

    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
      return response.data;
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
console.log("fine");

function submit ($http){
    console.log("funzione");
    var data = {};
    console.clear();
    var link = 'http://<path>/api/apiFix.php';
    var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
    $http.post(link, {giorno: data.giorno, ora: data.ora, mail: mail})
        .then(function (res){
            console.log("Dentro http.post");
            var response = res.data;
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

**FORM HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="demo"  ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
                <form ng-submit="submit()">
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Giorno:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="data.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Ora:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: data.giorno.date}" ng-model="data.ora" ng-disabled="!data.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item item-toggle">
                    &Egrave un'urgenza?
                    <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div align="center">
                <input class="button button-calm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Prenota !">            
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

I have no errors in console but the function "submit" it isn't execute.

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: submit isn't in the controller and you should use as ctrl.submit().

Comment: thank's, how can i call this function? @taguenizy

Comment: I've submitted an answer with the 3 errors I detected. Give a look and let me know if you have any further issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors. You need to fix at least these

On your controller (you will need to inject `$http`)

```
DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService', '$http'];

function DefaultController(dataService, $http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function (){
        console.log("funzione");
        var data = vm.form; // IMPORTANT
        console.clear();
        var link = 'http://<path>/api/apiFix.php';
        var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
        $http.post(link, {giorno: data.giorno, ora: data.ora, mail: mail})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                var response = res.data;
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
}
```

And in your form as I mention in the comment, since you are using the `controller as` approach you need to include `ctrl`

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
```

And rename your `ng-model` variables to

```
ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" //ng-model="data.ora" 
ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno" //ng-model="data.giorno"
```

Comment: thank's, it work's but now i've another question, how can send to the server the choice of the select? with my code i post all the possible choices

Comment: That's reflected on the `ng-model`. This should be in `vm.data` when submitting, if anything was selected. Could you provide more details

Comment: i test it selecting a day and a time and from the server print to the app (response) what it receives from the app and the result in the console is that i have all the data in the two selects

Comment: Could you check `vm.data` on the submit function

Comment: in vm.data there 2 of 3 and 72 elements that are all the data in the selects

Comment: @Edoardo You are using `vm.data` to populate and send data. I've updated answer, update in `submit` function `var data = vm.form;` and update your `ng-model` and it should work correctly

Comment: i've tested it and in vm.form i received an object with two elements: giorno and ora, in giorno i have date = 28/11/2016 and in ora i have date = 25/11/2016 and time = 09:00 but i've tested it selecting 28/11/2016 and 09:00 like time the 25/11/2016 is an error...

Comment: I guess that's how you have your data wired up. You need to update the rest of your code to contemplate the changes done. Like your `ng-options` and `ng-disable`

Comment: ok, i had an error in the filter, now it works, is it possible take like value an index of the select and not the day or time?

Comment: It is but you need to do some further changes. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options. Or in the submit you could check it against `vm.data` with `indexOf` and update your request parameters