# Get selected index from select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
```

I wan to get select index value, I try to use:

```
$scope.selected
```

But I get params from the database instead of the index of the selected list. How can I get that Index? Regards

I try as maddockst comment:

```
$scope.filtro = function (item) {
    $scope.Catalogos.indexOf(item);
}
```

But when I use it I get other values instead of index
[image]

**There is how I have now:**

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="Catalogos as item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
```

**JS**

```
function editar() {
    $scope.filtro = function (item) {
        alert($scope.Catalogos.indexOf(item));
        console.log(index);
    }

    ($("#tabla_catalogos tr.selected").hasClass("selected"));
    {
        var table = $('#tabla_catalogos').DataTable();
        var row = table.rows('.selected').data();
        var id = table.cell(row[0], 1).data();
        //Toma el id referente a la columna seleccionada
        $state.go("root.detalleregistros", { codigo: row[0].Codigo, nombre: row[0].Nombre, catalogoid: row[0].ID, catalogoselected: $scope.filtro });

    }
}
```

But I always get `-1` into alert[image]

Comment: A plunker or more details would be useful.

Comment: You're setting `ng-model` to `selected` and using `ng-options`. Therefore, when a user selects something, `selected` will be set to the `item` from `Catalogos` corresponding to the item selected. If you want the index, use `$index`. See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan pretty sure `$index` doesn't exist on `ng-options`

Comment: @maddockst It is if you use `track by $index`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no, it doesn't.

Comment: @Gerardo check [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options). It may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `filtro`, you could get the index of the selected item in the `Catalogos` array using the following code:

Change the `filtro` function to:

```
$scope.filtro = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.Catalogos.indexOf(item);
}
```

Comment: I try as your comment but I dont reach index, I update my question with my try

Comment: @Gerardo you aren't doing anything with `$scope.Catalogos.indexOf(item);`. Try wrapping it in a `console` like so: `console.log($scope.Catalogos.indexOf(item));`.

Comment: I do it and I always get `-1`

Comment: I want this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/30/) so I try to change my ng-options as `ng-options="Catalogos.indexOf(item) item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"` but it no works

Comment: @Gerardo im being thick. Change `ng-change` back to `ng-change="filtro(selected)"`

Comment: I return ng-change but I getting null trying to get it

Comment: That should work. Take a look at this fiddle which does exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/whpjgfyx/2/

Comment: If I can access to value using `$scope.Catalogos[0]`, or `$scope.Catalogos[1]`, etc, there are no way to get actual `$scope.Catalogos`?

Comment: @Gerardo yes. The fiddle shows a working example doing just that.

Comment: I really try it but It returns always -1, I post all my function if you can check it I appreciated it

Comment: I upload it, I really don´t know what is wrong I see all correct!

Comment: Your `ng-options` should be: `ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"`

Comment: Yes, I change it but same result, just returns -1

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunkr please?

Comment: OMG, I create a fiddle and it works, I don´t have an idea why isn´t works into my app[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w5XT/1365/)

Comment: I can't really help you much further with that :-/

Comment: difference between fiddle and my code is that I don´t have `ng-controller` , I need it?

Comment: Make sure your code locally matches the fiddle completely. You will need the `ng-controller` ... I can't see how it would ever work without it.

Comment: any idea why item come null? If I console it before reach alert it throw "true"

Answer (score -1):

SO in this scenario if you go into dev tools, I assume chrome and go to your console tab.  Type $scope.selected, it will give you the object definition and from there you'll see your selected index value.

It will have to be something like $scope.selected[0].value