# Dropdown binding issue with track by

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting problem while binding my dropdown value with associative array.

Problem is with track by so like when I don't add track by to my dropdown then I have my binding with dropdown and when I add track by then O am unable to auto select dropdown value.

I want to use track by with ng-options so that angular js doesn't add
$$hashKey and leverage performance benefit associated with track by.

I am not getting why this behaviour is happening.

Note: I only want to bind **name of choices** like **Pizza or burger** for each of my **$scope.items and not whole object**.

**Update:** As I understand and with so much trying with current data structure of my $scope.items it is not working with ng-options and I want to use ng-options with track by to avoid generating hash key by Angular js. I also tried ng-change as suggested by @MarcinMalinowski but I am getting key as undefined.

So what should be my data structure of $scope.items so that when I need to access any item from my $scope.items? I can access it without doing loop (like we access items from associative array) like how I can access now with correct data structure and using ngoptions only with track by.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
  {
    "title": "1",
    "myChoice" :"",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc",
          "$$hashKey": "object:417"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr",
          "$$hashKey": "object:418"
        }
      }
   },
   {
    "title": "2",
     "myChoice" :"",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc",
          "$$hashKey": "object:417"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr",
          "$$hashKey": "object:418"
        }
      }
   }
  ];
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div ng-repeat="data in items">
       <div>{{data.title}}
       </div>
     <select ng-model="data.myChoice" 
     ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in data.choices track by $index"><option value="">Select Connection</option></select>
   </div>
   
   </ul>
```

Comment: Why not `track by $index`

Comment: @MaximShoustin Adding trackby $index is always autoselecting last item.See my update i have added the $index and now i am unable to select any other items

Comment: When referring to yourself ("I"), please always use a capital letter. This will save some volunteer editors some work when improving your posts (presumably all 278 of them have the same errors). Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problems in your code are:

1) [`track by $index` is not supported by `ngOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916726/angularjs-using-index-in-ng-options), it will result the value of the `option` to be `undefined`(in your case it will be an `$index` of `ngRepeat`);

2) `track by` doesn't work well with object data-sources (it is supposed to be used with array data-sources), [from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage):

> trackexpr: Used when working with an array of objects. The result of
>   this expression will be used to identify the objects in the array.

Of course, you can use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to generate `option` elements, but personally, I would prefer using [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) without `track by` due to the benefits it has over [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

**UPDATE:** Here is the code that illustrates how you can change your initial data-source and use `track by` to pre-select an option in case the model is an object. But even in the first example `console.log()` shows that `$$hashKey` was not added to `choices` object.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.items = [
  {
    "title": "1",
    "myChoice" :"burger",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr"
        }
      }
   },
   {
    "title": "2",
     "myChoice" :"",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr"
        }
      }
   }
  ];
  
  $scope.itemsTransformed = angular.copy($scope.items).map(function(item){
    delete item.myChoice;
    item.choices = Object.keys(item.choices).map(function(choice){
        item.choices[choice].name = choice;
        return item.choices[choice];
    });
    return item;
  });
  
  //select an option like an object, not a string
  $scope.itemsTransformed[1].myChoice = $scope.itemsTransformed[1].choices[0];
  
  $timeout(function() {
    //changes a prop in opts array - options are not-re-rendered in the DOM
    //the same option is still selected
    $scope.itemsTransformed[1].choices[0].arg = "xyz";
  }, 3000);
  
  $scope.selectionChanged =function(key, items){
    console.log(items); //as we can see $$hashKey wasn't added to choices props
  };
   
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <p>Without track by:</p>
   <div ng-repeat="data in items track by data.title">
     <div>{{data.title}} - {{data.myChoice}}</div>
       
     <select ng-model="data.myChoice" 
             ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in data.choices"
             ng-change="selectionChanged(key, items)">
       <option value="">Select Connection</option>
     </select>
     
   </div>
   <hr/>
    <p>Using track by name to pre-select an option:</p>
    <div ng-repeat="data in itemsTransformed track by data.title">
     <div>{{data.title}} - {{data.myChoice}}</div>
       
     <select ng-model="data.myChoice" 
             ng-options="choice as choice.name for choice in data.choices track by choice.name"
             ng-change="selectionChanged(key, itemsTransformed)">
       <option value="">Select Connection</option>
     </select>
     
   </div>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 2:** A simple example that shows us the fact `$$hashKey` property is not added to the objects when using `ngOptions` without `track by`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr"
        }
      };

    $scope.selectionChanged = function (key, items) {
        console.log($scope.items);
    };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <hr/>
    <p>Example without track by:</p>

    <select ng-model="myChoice"
            ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in items"
            ng-change="selectionChanged(myChoice, items)">
        <option value="">Select Connection</option>
    </select> 
    <hr/>
    {{myChoice}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE 3:** Final result below (that work with angularjs versions < 1.4, for 1.4+ I would recommend changing the data structure as `$scope.itemsTransformed` in the first code snippet):

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("MyController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            "title": "1",
            "myChoice": "burger",
            "choices": {
                "pizza": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "arg": "abc"
                },
                "burger": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "arg": "pqr"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "2",
            "myChoice": "",
            "choices": {
                "pizza": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "arg": "abc"
                },
                "burger": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "arg": "pqr"
                }
            }
        }
    ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="data in items track by data.title">
        <div>{{data.title}} {{data.myChoice}}</div>

        <select ng-model="data.myChoice"
                ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in data.choices">
            <option value="">Select Connection</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but does ng-options without track by have performance benefit over ng-repeat??

Comment: Problem with ng-options without track generates hash by which I stated in my question and I dont want that.That is why I want to use track by so that angular doesnt generate hash by to track changes

Comment: @Learning, tried removing `track by` from `ngOptions` and I don't see `$$hashKey` being created (Will add the code to illustrate. ). `track by` with `ngRepeat` makes sense in terms of performance, but I'm not sure it plays the same role in `ngOptions` directive - as from the docs it is used to  preserve the selection when the options are recreated.

Comment: @Learning Added the code snippet, please check. As stated in the docs `ngOptions` directive has performance benefits over `ngRepeat` (there is nothing about using `track by` to improve its performance and I don't see something related in [the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/21a2f4bb2310f5cea69d637568ca6c21f2815270/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L335)) as well. Where did you get that info that `track by` affects the performance of `ngOptions`? Btw in the snippet you are using angularjs v1.2, I recommend upgrading it if you care about performance in general :)

Comment: WIthout track is adding hashkey in your first example.I am not getting why you have used timeout in your code of second example

Comment: I see `{
    "title": "1",
    "myChoice": "pizza",
    "choices": {
      "pizza": {
        "type": 1,
        "arg": "abc"
      },
      "burger": {
        "type": 1,
        "arg": "pqr"
      }
    },
    "$$hashKey": "003"
  }` and `$$hashKey` was added to `data` object in `ng-repeat="data in items"`. Nothing was added with using `ngOptions` directive. In second example timeout was used to illustrate that the object was changed, but the selection was not, since `track by` was used in `ngOptions` and it identifies the object by property.

Comment: @Learning I've added one more example to show that `$$hashKey` is not added while using `ngOptions` without `track by`.

Comment: But does this store selected item for each of my $scope.data like for title1 i selected pizza and for title 2 i selected burger so does this selection will persist?

Comment: @Learning this was just an example, to proof you that `$$hashKey` was not added with `ngOptions`. And of course it shows that you can easily use the first example of my first code snippet. I've added `track by data.title` to the first repeater, so right now you will not see `$$hashKey` in the logs at all.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer but as you said i can use first example of first code snippet so do i have to use $scope.itemsTransformed and timeout code also??

Comment: @Learning, you don't have to use `$scope.itemsTransformed` and `$timeout`. Added final code snippet.

Comment: But without track by how it is not adding hashkey.I am bit confused.Let me check in my code

Comment: Yes, sure you should try it. `ngOptions` directive works different comparing to `ngRepeat`, so that is why `$$hashKey` is not added even without `track by` (as I mentioned earlier `track by` is used to identify an object and set the selection).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

`ngOptions` doesn't create new scope like `ngRepeat` directive per item therefore you don't need to take care about to get rid of `$$hashKey`

I would use `ng-repeat` to iterate on `<option>` (suppose you don't create long lists):

```
<select ng-model="data.myChoice">    
    <option value="">Select Connection</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key , value) in data.choices track by key" ng-value="key" title="{{key}}"
    >{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[Working Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1j2uruwk/)</kbd>

---

Take look on this issue: [github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564) - *ng-options track by and select as are not compatible*

I believe this issue still exists so suggest you to use `ngRepeat` with `track by` instead. For small list there is no performance penalty

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but can you explain me a little bit about this like what was the problem in my code and why not ng-options ??

Comment: @Learning there is no problem in your code but complicated structure. So I replaced `ngOptions` directive with basic `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Learning Take look on this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564 - ng-options track by and select as are not compatible

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for the  element using the array or object

ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is important to know when binding the select to a model that is an object or a collection.

1.If you set the model to an object that is equal to an object in your collection, ngOptions won't be able to set the selection, because the objects are not identical. So by default, you should always reference the item in your collection for preselections, e.g.: $scope.selected = $scope.collection[3]

2. ngOptions will track the identity of the item not by reference, but by the result of the track by expression. For example, if your collection items have an id property, you would track by item.id.

For Example :

```
 $scope.items = [
  {
    "title": "1",
    "myChoice" :"",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr"
        }
      }
   },
   {
    "title": "2",
     "myChoice" :"",
      "choices": {
        "pizza": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "abc"
        },
        "burger": {
          "type": 1,
          "arg": "pqr"
        }
      }
   }
  ];
```

From the above 2nd point, track the identity of the item not by reference.

Add keyName of key in the object  and track by keyName or track by arg , type.

**Track by arg or type :**

```
 <select ng-model="data.myChoice" 
                 ng-options="choice as choice.arg for choice in data.choices track by choice.arg">
           <option value="">Select Connection</option>
         </select>
```

Or **add keyName inside the choice object**

```
 $scope.items = $scope.items.filter(function(item){
    delete item.myChoice;
    item.choices = Object.keys(item.choices).map(function(choice){
        item.choices[choice].keyName = choice;
        return item.choices[choice];
    });
    return item;
  });
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ul>
   <div ng-repeat="data in items">
     <select ng-model="data.selected" 
             ng-options="choice as choice.keyName for choice in data.choices track by choice.keyName"
             ng-change="selection(data.selected)">
       <option value="">Select</option>
     </select>

   </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Demo Link [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dyRkbV7Ab2za1VAUVf1j?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `ng-change` and pass/use your ng-model value there to get any property you wish.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but I am little bit confused here.if I set value of my ng-model there then what should be my ng-model in select. Can you please add any samply code of what you are saying please??

Comment: `ng-change="youFuncHere(key)"`

Comment: But when i dont add ng-model in my dropdown then i get an error :Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!So are you saying that i specify ng-model but still set my model in youFuncHere method??

Comment: Not sure this answer is somehow related to the `ngOptions` usage.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="form-control pickupaddress ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched m-r-sm m-t-n-xs" ng-model="item.pickup_address" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" ng-options="add._id as add.nick_name for add in addPerFood[item.food._id] | unique:'nick_name'" ng-change="dropDownSelect(item.pickup_address,allCarts,item,$index)">
```

Comment: please try to explain more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)